# How to execute ms word VBA with JACOB

Tags: java, vba, ms-word, jacob

I added a VBA procedure (***saveasdoc***) to **Normal.dot**.

I have tested it with a .docx file:

1. Saves the opened file with same name to a new **.doc** file.
2. Exits the application MS Word.

I want to run this VBA procedure from a Java Application using the JACOB library.

Here is what I have tried :

```
System.out.println("Start!!");
File docfile = new File("C:/test.docx");
ActiveXComponent word = new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
word.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));
Dispatch oDocuments = word.getProperty("Documents").toDispatch();
Dispatch.call(oDocuments, "saveasdoc()", docfile.getPath()).toDispatch();
System.out.println("End!!");
```

The MS Word app is shown and the document is loaded, but the only *claimed* macro executor code is generating an exception :

```
SEVERE: null
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: saveasdoc()
  at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Native Method)
  at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:625)
  at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:625)
  at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.callN(Dispatch.java:453)
  at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.call(Dispatch.java:541)
  at WordProcessing.main(WordProcessing.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want Application.Run ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220716(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220716%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

Not tested but the general direction you should be pursuing:

```
System.out.println("Start!!");
File docfile = new File("C:/test.docx");
ActiveXComponent application = new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
Dispatch.call(application, "Run", new Variant("saveasdoc"), new Variant(docfile.getPath()));
System.out.println("End!!");
```